# Copy file if timestamp is updated

Tags: batch-file, file-transfer, vbscript

I'm searching for a script which can copy a file **ONLY** when the timestamp is updated.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: Not clear: Don't describe a complicated process when you are asking for only one script. Please limit the discussion for this one script and what it should do.

Comment: If the time stamp is being updated on a file in Folder 2, that means the archive attribute has been set.  When you copy a file from one folder to another you can have the archive attribute turned off on the source. I believe XCOPY and ROBOCOPY can both do this.

Comment: Hey @harrymc i've updated the question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @squashman Thanks for your answer, i will look into it! :)